# How to combine datatable and HTML in renderUI when developing a FlexdashBoard app.?

Tags: html, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am sure that no one helped me, tk. I just [asked the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443069/how-to-applying-and-filtering-imported-data-into-the-flaxdashboard-app) not very correctly earlier.
I am trying to create a FlexDashcoard application. To understand how the program works, you need the [sample data files](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/-WKsNqCr82KnPA?w=1) that I have prepared. I apologize in advance for the Russian characters in the files, they are presented to you "as is".

Here is my code:

````html
---
title: "AFEA of Russian enterprises"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: simplex
runtime: shiny
---

```{r GlobalOptions}
options(knitr.duplicate.label = 'allow')
rv <- reactiveValues(txt_file  = FALSE)
OKVEDselectInputChoices<- reactiveValues(data  = NULL)
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
### Library connection module  ###
library("flexdashboard")
library("dygraphs")
library("shiny")
library("shinyFiles")
library("DT")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("here")
library("data.table")
library("plyr")
### ----------------------------- ###
```

## Sidebar {.sidebar}
```{r}
roots <- c('C' = 'C:/', 'D' = 'D:/', '//' = '\\\\ns\\Public\\Power BI')

renderUI({
  shinyFilesButton("files_choose", "Select files", "",
                   multiple=TRUE,
                   buttonType = "default",
                   class = NULL,
                   icon = icon("list-alt"),
                   style = "background-image: linear-gradient(#D9230F, #D9230F 6%, #D9230F); 
                            border-color:  #A91B0C;
                            margin-top: 10px;
                            width: 100%;
                            float: left;
                            box-sizing: border-box;",
                    viewtype = "detail"
  )
})
br()
renderUI({
  actionButton(inputId = "apply", 
                         label = "Apply", 
                         icon = icon("play"),
                         style = "background-image: linear-gradient(#D9230F, #D9230F 6%, #D9230F);
                                  border-color:  #A91B0C;
                                  margin-top: 10px;
                                  margin-bottom: 10px;
                                  width: 100%;
                                  float: left;
                                  box-sizing: border-box;"
  )
})
br()
renderUI({h6(inputId="sideBarText2", "Выбор ОКВЭД(ов):")})
renderUI({
     selectInput("OKVEDlectInput", 
                  label = NULL,
                  choices = OKVEDselectInputChoices$data,
                  #selected = "Percent White")
                  multiple=TRUE
    )
})
```

```{r}
shinyFileChoose(input, "files_choose", 
                 roots=roots,
                 filetypes=c('csv'))

rv_result <- eventReactive(
  input$apply,{
    if (!is.null(input$files_choose))
      {
        myInputFile <- parseFilePaths(roots,input$files_choose)$datapath
        
        all.files <- myInputFile
        print(all.files)
        a.vector <- grep("data\\-\\d+\\-structure\\-",  all.files, ignore.case = TRUE)
        print(a.vector)
        all.files <- all.files[a.vector]
        all.files<- sort(all.files)
        
        n <- length(all.files)
        print(n)
        data = vector('list', n)
        
        if (n>0) {
          for (i in 2:(n+1)) {
            #print(paste("Вот такой файл:" , all.files[i-1]))
            data[i-1] <- lapply(all.files[i-1],
                              fread,
                              showProgress = TRUE,
                              sep = ";",
                              quote = "",
                              header = FALSE,
                              stringsAsFactors=TRUE,
                              select = c(1:124))
          }
        }
    }
    table <- rbindlist(data)
    UN <- unique(table[[5]])
    UN <-  sort(UN)
    OKVEDselectInputChoices$data <- UN
    rv$txt_file <- table
    rv_result <- rv$txt_file
    #View(rv$txt_file)
  }
)

```

### Basic information

```{r}

#renderTable({
#      dataset <- rv_result()
#      dataset
#})

f <- function(verlist, list_for_ver, resulttyp=0,delna=1) {
  # verlist - массив, который требуется проверить на совпадение с элементами второго массива
  # list_for_ver - проверочный массив, т.е. тот, с которым сравнимается
  # resulttyp (0 - выводятся номера элементов list_for_ver, которые найдены);
  #           (1 - выводятся найденные значения)
  # delna -   (0 -если элемент не найде, то он не показывается)
  #           (1 -если элемент не найде, то указывается NA)
  listforreturn <- vector(mode = 'list', length=0)
  if ((class(verlist)=='list') && (class(list_for_ver)=='list')){
    if (delna==1){
      listforreturn <- as.vector(na.omit(match(verlist,list_for_ver)))
    }
    else{
      listforreturn <- as.vector(match(verlist,list_for_ver))
    }
    
    if (resulttyp==0){
      listforreturn <- as.list(listforreturn)
    }
    else{
      listforreturn<- as.list(list_for_ver[listforreturn])
    }
  }
  return(listforreturn)
}


dataset <- reactive({rv_result()})

renderUI({
      data <- dataset()
      if (is.null(input$OKVEDlectInput)) {
        data <- dataset()
      }
      else{
        d1 <- as.list(input$OKVEDlectInput)
        d2 <- as.list(as.vector(data$V5))
        result <- which(!is.na(f(d2, d1,0,0)))
        result <- as.vector(result)
        data <- data[result,]
      }
      
      div(HTML("География анлиза насчитывает "),
          datatable(data, fillContainer=getOption("DT.fillContainer", TRUE)))
})

```




### Secondary information


Some commentary about Frame 2.
````

[You can download the finished version of the code](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/fW5Fx31bf3Z8mA)

My application first creates an interface, allows the user to select a file to import (or several), but with a specific name, and loads these data into the application.

On this line, I create a mapping:

```
div(HTML("География анлиза насчитывает "),
          datatable(data, fillContainer=getOption("DT.fillContainer", TRUE)))
```

It looks strange. If not add`fillContainer=getOption("DT.fillContainer", TRUE)`, then the scroll bar disappears from the table. When you add this element, everything shrinks to a very narrow size:

[image]

I am unable to stretch the table to the bottom for the rest of the free space.

I specially prepared a short version of the code, from which the problem is kind and easy to repeat using a ready-made data array.

````html
---
title: "AFEA of Russian enterprises"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: simplex
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library("flexdashboard")
library("DT")

```

## Sidebar {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------
```{r}
```
### Chart A
```{r}
renderUI({
    data <- iris
    div(HTML("География анлиза насчитывает "),
      datatable(data, fillContainer=getOption("DT.fillContainer", TRUE)))
})
```
````

Comment: You don't need to share your entire application code with us. Can you reduce the code and share only the part of the code which is required to reproduce the issue? Can you use some default dataset (like `mtcars`, `iris`) to reproduce the problem so that it does not require us to download dataset from an external link?

Comment: @RonakShah Shah. I specially prepared a short version of the code, from which the problem is kind and easy to repeat using a ready-made data array. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to increase/decrease width and height of datatable. I have added `style = "height: 175%"` in `div` to increase the height.

````
---
title: "AFEA of Russian enterprises"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: simplex
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library("flexdashboard")
library("DT")

```

## Sidebar {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------
```{r}
```
### Chart A
```{r}
renderUI({
    data <- iris
    div(HTML("География анлиза насчитывает "),
      datatable(data, fillContainer=getOption("DT.fillContainer", TRUE)), style = "height: 175%")
})
```
````

[image]

Comment: Scrolls disappear with this option

Comment: I don't know about that. Did you try `options = list(scrollX = TRUE)` or other options from here ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765338/how-to-make-the-horizontal-scrollbar-visible-in-dtdatatable

Comment: No, I'm not! I don't understand how to do it in flexdashboard. And if you use your method, then when you change the scale of the window, there will also be unpleasant consequences. But you can't set the size as a percentage.